# php imagick script ends with error 500

Tags: php, iis, imagemagick, imagick, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a simple php script that is converting a pdf to jpg file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$pdf_file   = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pbdev\10001.pdf';
$save_to    = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pbdev\daten\demo.jpg';

$img = new imagick();

//this must be called before reading the image, otherwise has no effect - "-density {$x_resolution}x{$y_resolution}"
//this is important to give good quality output, otherwise text might be unclear
$img->setResolution(200,200);

//read the pdf
$img->readImage("{$pdf_file}[0]");

//reduce the dimensions - scaling will lead to black color in transparent regions
$img->scaleImage(800,0);

//set new format
$img->setImageFormat('jpg');

// -flatten option, this is necessary for images with transparency, it will produce white background for transparent regions
$img = $img->flattenImages();

//save image file
$img->writeImages($save_to, false);

?>
```

The script ends with Error 500

Logfile gives only this warning:

```
[17-Jul-2018 09:21:43 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Version warning: Imagick was compiled against Image Magick version 1683 but version 26896 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: The compiled Imagick version is 1683, but the PHP loaded 26896.
So try to Reinstall the PHP and Re compile it with the correct version of Imagick... 
Your code seems like working one.

Comment: What to recompile? How to recompile? Why reinstall PHP? How to reinstall PHP? Its only a Package with a system-variable and known in iis, nothing to install or compile..

Comment: Dude, the log file clearly describes that was wrongly compiled.!! So you need to re compile imagick according to the supported php version.
PHP 7 has some issues with the older Imagick.
So if you are using latest php try to recompile the Imagick with latest version.

I was guiding this because your error msg tells that.
Have a look at this https://www.58bits.com/blog/2018/04/23/installing-imagemagick-use-php-and-iis-windows-server-2012r2-and-windows-10

Comment: I am using ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x64, with ImageMagick 7.0 it isnt working at all

Comment: Dude i'm sorry, The error log shows compile issues, so the only way is try a reinstallation or recompiling the Imagick supported php version.

Comment: I compiled it new with https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html. But now i get an another error ... ´PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ImagickException: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(10001.pdf[0]) is not within the allowed path(s) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pbdev\pdf.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pbdev\pdf.php(14): Imagick->readimage('10001.pdf[0]')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pbdev\pdf.php on line 14´

Comment: Okay.
i think your php open_basedir is on. set it to off
Edit your php settings php.ini `open_basedir` to `none`.